# Home built in-dash Navigation system or programmable/open api after market one?

Tags: kia

I have decided it is cheaper to upgrade my paid off car than it is to buy a newer sweeter one. One thing I have craved for a long time is an in dash navigation system. Now I am a professional programmer and a budding hobbyist electrical engineer. I would like to have a in dash nav that I could access either via an api or one that I can write code for.

Is there any in dash navs for a 05-kia-spectra-EX that I can do this on for the cheap? I dont want to spend a ton of money.

So to summarize I would like either:

- After market in-dash nav that is programmable (preferably .NET but any language is fine really)
- Home built in-dash nav

Comment: Take a look at .NET Micro Framework (NETMF), and maybe more the NETMF Gadgeteer to achieve what you are trying to do. I'm will not going in details as it may belong to another site, but you can easily have a touch screen, a GPS and even an OBDII connector. And you'll just have to do the code!

Comment: a few comments: 1. this is close to a 'shop-for-me' question, which is discouraged per the FAQ. 2. you may be better served asking on the [electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) SX site.

Comment: @mac I have tried this on a couple stack exchanges and it keeps getting closed as off topic. I am not asking for anyone to shop for me I am trying to see what people in the field would suggest.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, and I hope you find the help you're looking for.

Comment: @mac do you have an opinion on this topic?

Comment: Perhaps [something like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__ZYWtcGeTY) could be adapted to suit your needs

Comment: @mac I think you misinterpreted what I was asking. Thank you for your comments though.

Comment: I am a little foggy on your question as well.  Could you make it a little clearer / more specific?

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous, you could always install a Galaxy Tab or Surface tablet in your car. While you're at it, go check out the OBD2 spec and how to interface with it via bluetooth.

Comment: The problem isn't getting a device really. The problem is getting a mount that fits in the center dash. I would love to see a mount for a surface tab that fits naturally in my center dash. I would buy it in a heartbeat. Also I have a bluetooth OBD2 module in there now. I love working with that thing. Would be very easy to integrate into a car dash program if I had a platform to work on

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of aftermarket, FOSS, navigation systems out there.

Physically, you're looking at a double DIN head unit, to fit the display. Nine times out of ten, these are running Windows CE (probably 6.0).

Personally, I have used Navit (http://www.navit.ie) as the routing software and help develop it for Windows CE, Android and Linux. It is written mostly in C.